# Светлый и темный режимы

Tags: javascript, css, css-filters

Помогите пожалуйста! Я хочу сделать темный режим на сайте, узнал об одной фишке, а именно про filter: invert(1); (что это свойство меняет все элементы на противоположные цвета). Попробовал сделать и все получилось, но я не могу изменять ничего в этом "ночном режиме", так как если я пропишу для какой-то из картинок, чтобы при клике на light все стало invert(1), а у imgLogo чтоб значение этого filter было none. Но оно не работает, подскажите, что я делаю не так!

```
let pageElements = document.querySelector('*');
let light = document.querySelector('.mode-day');
let dark = document.querySelector('.mode-night');
let imgLogo = document.querySelector('.logo-foto');

light.onclick = function() {
  pageElements.style.filter = "invert(1)";
  imgLogo.style.filter = "none";
  light.style.display = "none";
  dark.style.display = "flex";
}

dark.onclick = function() {
  pageElements.style.filter = "none";
  light.style.display = "flex";
  dark.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: «подскажите, что я делаю не так» — используете `invert()` для всех элементов на странице)) Это невероятно дорогая операция. Что, если при клике добавить запись в localStorage, а JS будет добавлять на страницу один или другой CSS в зависимости от этой записи?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME: ну, это же ещё одни стили прописывать... А так - опа! В одну строку))

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, всё равно он его использует неправильно. Не говоря уж о том, что он его прописал не элементам, а коллекции. Кстати, даже не прописал - там же две точки, оно валится на первой же строке обработчика.

Comment: @UModeL, в одну строчку делается гораздо проще, а не так :)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME 21, вы говорите что проще сделать через localStorage, но я уже пробовал этот вариант и при смене стилей было видно на миг страницу без стилей (только html). Из-за этого пришлось искать другой способ, вот решил просто поменять всему цвета на противоположные. Повторяю, что все работает, но не могу отредактировать конечный результат

Comment: @COTRIKS Касаемо "видно HTML": Можно было прямо из head вставить основные цвета через `<script> document.head.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", "<style> body { background-color: #111; } </style>"); </script>` а детали уже загрузить через CSS файл...

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('invert')
})
```

```css
html, body {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

body.invert, body.invert img {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<p>Инвертировать надо только body и картинки
<p>А остальное - не надо.
<p>Вот: <button>invert</button>
```